# Unwind Segue with UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboard, uibarbuttonitem

I've successfully implemented an unwind segue based on the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)

What I can't get to work is using a BarButton Item to trigger the unwind, as opposed to a Button. The Button item triggers the segue correctly, but when I connect the BarButton Item to the method below, no transition occurs at all.

```
- (IBAction)unwindSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *)segue 
{
    // Do Something    
}
```

I've used a BarButton item to trigger a push segue before, so I'm not sure why I can't also use it trigger an unwind segue. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IB you need to drag from VC2 down to the green Exit icon at the bottom of your VC2 and select the unwind segue from the list corresponding to VC1. This will wire VC2 to the unwind in VC1. To "trigger" this you can do something like this:

VC2

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

    // use a conditional like this if you want to use this action method for multiple buttons
    // Otherwise, just call performSegueWithIdentifier
    if (barButton == self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myStoryboardIdForVC1" sender:self];
    }
}
```

VC1

```
- (IBAction)unwindToVC1:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    // use condidtionals like this if you want to use the unwind from multiple sources
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mySegueIdfromVC2"]) {
       // do something
    }
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mySegueIdfromVC3"]) {
       // do something
    }
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mySegueIdfromVC4"]) {
       // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I did make sure the VC2's UIBarButtonItem  is connected to VC1's unwind segue. I just tried to connect the UIBarButtonItem to an action as shown: 

`- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}`

But when the UIBarButtonItem, VC2 still doesn't unwind to VC1. Did I miss something obvious?

Comment: I have some more thoughts, let's chat about them here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61079/unwind-seguea

Comment: Apparently I need a 20 reputation to chat in the chat room (I only have 18 :/ )

Comment: I tried adding changing the IBACtion to `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];`, but that didn't seem to work, either.

Comment: Wire the ViewController directly to the Exit (unwind segue). When you dismiss it should unwind

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! All working now---part of my problem was that I forgot to add the identifier of the Storyboard Unwind Segue in IB!